# Regex to print out all the matches inside ? and , or )

Tags: java, regex

I have a collection of Strings saved in 2d array.
the string has a shape of horn-clause and the complete one string can be in the form of patient(?x) as well as hasdoctor(?x,?y)

if i write the ?x=alex and ?y=john then the above string takes a structure of

patient(alex)
hasdoctor(alex, john)

Now the Question is when is use the below code it finds the ?x, but in the hasdoctor(?x,?y) it skips the ?y .

```
void find_var(String[][] temp)
{
    System.out.println(temp.length);
    System.out.println(temp[0].length);
    for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<temp[0].length-1;j++)
        {
           String text_to_parse=temp[i][j];
           Pattern y = Pattern.compile("[?]\\w[,)]");
           Matcher z= y.matcher(text_to_parse);
           if(z.find())
           {
               System.out.println("Found at::"+temp[i][j]);
               System.out.println(z.group());

           }
           else
           {
               System.out.println("Not found at::"+temp[i][j]);
           }
}}
```

the pesudo code i can explain that i want in java is

```
if([?]\\w[,) is found in array[][])
  if([?]\\w[,) is already in other_array[]
    Then skip;
  else
    save [?]\\w[,) to other_array[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't say that I completely understand what you're trying to achieve, but I think the problem is that you're using

```
if (z.find()) { /* ... */ }
```

instead of

```
while (z.find()) { /* ... */ }
```

Using `if`, the string will not be completely consumed and it will return after the first match is found.